# Emacs key binding to f3 resulting in a yank instead

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, emacs23

**Solution:**

So I found the solution ... and do I feel stupid. The problem was not anything to do with emacs at all - it was to do with my keyboard.

So my keyboard has this button which I never use and guess I accidentally pressed called 'F-lock'. I can't post images due to low reputation so see this link for an image: http://az623152.vo.msecnd.net/library/images/2774431.jpg

Toggling F-lock completely changes the functionality of the F buttons. So F3 had become 'Redo' and F4 had become 'New'. So whenever I was actually pressing F3 the computer was not actually even receiving it as f3 but rather
'Redo'.

Thank you for all the comments in helping to debug the problem. Sorry for the time waste!

**Original Question:**

I have been using f3 in emacs to define a new macro, f4 to finish the definition and f4 again to run the macro for quite some time now.

However, for some reason when I press f3 now it results in a yank instead of the intended macro behaviour.

If I press 'C h k' and then f3 I sometimes get the following (redacted) response:

```
C-y runs the command org-yank, which is an interactive compiled Lisp
function.
It is bound to C-y.
```

Sometimes I get this:

```
C-y runs the command yank, which is an interactive compiled Lisp
function.
It is bound to C-y, <S-insertchar>, <S-insert>, <menu-bar> <edit>
<paste>.
(yank &optional ARG)
```

The result of doing the same with f4:

```
 C-n runs the command next-line, which is an interactive compiled Lisp
 function.
 It is bound to C-n, <down>.
 (next-line &optional ARG TRY-VSCROLL)
```

The only recent thing I have started to do is use emacs' org-mode.
How can I get my keys back to their original behaviour? What exactly is causing them to behave like this?

Update:

***are you running under terminal or x?***

Not running under the terminal - currently using the GUI interface.

***when did the change in behavior happen? what was it associated with? new package installation? switch from terminal to X or back? reboot?***

There are two things I can think of which may be causing this:
I just recently started using AucTex (v 11.88.6) and org mode. 
The 'C h k' f3 sometimes responds that it is bound to org-yank (see above) so I'm leaning towards thinking its something to do with org mode.

***Does this behavior also occur when you start emacs with the -Q option?*** 
Yes, even with the -Q option specified the same behaviour results.

Comment: please specify the platform and emacs version

Comment: @sds operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and 'M-x emacs-version' returns: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7) of 2014-03-07 on lamiak, modified by Debian

Comment: are you running under terminal or X? when did the change in behavior happen? what was it associated with? new package installation? switch from terminal to X or back? reboot? (please put all the details into the question body, not the comments)

Comment: Does this behavior also occur when you start emacs with the `-Q` option?

Comment: What @Thomas said - that's the first thing to check. It looks as if, for whatever reason, Emacs is seeing the key `F3` as `C-y` and the key `F4` as `C-n`. And it looks like this `F3` interpretation has nothing to do with Org mode, since you say that you see the same interpretation as `C-y` even without Org mode. Anyway, check `emacs -Q`. If you don't see the problem with `emacs -Q` then recursively bisect your init file to see what is causing the problem.

Comment: I've updated the question details to answer all of your questions. Even with -Q flag given the behaviour occurs.

Comment: your wasted time saved me some. thanks for leaving this up!